# Connect GoPro Hero5 Session to Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch, streaming-video

I am doing project using Raspberry Pi 3 model B. For the video capture I have decided to use GoPro Hero5 Session camera. But now I can not find a way to get the input video from it to Raspberry Pi. My code is working for other USB cameras. I tried with connection via USB cable.

I am in a serious situation since a had spend lot of money for the GoPro camera.

Can anyone suggest me a way get out of trouble?

Answer (score 2):

Less of an answer but more as an extended comment for other searchers:

The GoPro 3 was the last version that I know of that was flexible enough to be seen as hackable. 
Other alternative cameras are a lot easier to work with, notably the [Gitup](https://www.gitup.com) cameras.

That said check out this https://github.com/konradit/goprostream

and this thread:
 https://github.com/KonradIT/goprowifihack/issues/62

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can not stream live video trough USB from a GoPro camera. And you can only get a low quality preview stream over Wi-Fi.

The Pi cameras are the best option for any kind of video streaming on a Pi as you can use hardware encoding and other features of the GPU. And they are cheap.